# bias and consistency what if one of the sample is exactly same as expectation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

For the given sample,
$$
\{ X_1, X_2 , ... , X_N \}  
$$

I just wanted to see if the estimator is biased and/or consistent if
$$
X_i  = \hat{\mu} ,\ \forall i \in N
$$

In this case, I think it is unbiased and consistent since the expectation is same, and the variance converges to 0 as N gets larger.

Does it still hold even for the following condition?

$$
\hat{\mu} = X_2
$$

I think the estimator is still unbiased and consistent.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this question does not make much sense as, assuming from the title of the question that $\hat\mu$ represents $\mathbb E[X_i]$ (instead of an estimator of $\mathbb E[X_i]$), the only case when $X_i=\hat\mu$ for all $i$'s is when the random variables are not random.

And if $X_i=\hat\mu$ for one of the $X_i$'s, one would have to know *which one in* the $X_i$'s is involved, which is only possible for a limited number of instance. For instance, if the $X_i$'s are distributed over $\{\hat\mu-1,\hat\mu,\hat\mu+1\}$ and one observes all three different values among the $X_i$'s then $\hat\mu$ is known exactly.

If instead (see comment below), $\hat\mu$ represents an estimator of $\mathbb E[X_i]$, then $$\hat\mu(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=X_2$$
is indeed an unbiased estimator of the expectation $\mathbb E[X_i]$, but not an efficient one, in most cases. In particular, it is not consistent since it does not change with the sample size $n$. (The alternative interpretation when $\hat\mu(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is equal to one (or more) of the $X_i$'s for a given sample does not imply that $\hat\mu$ is imbiased.)

Comment: I am sorry for such confusion. bias = E[mu hat] -  mu , so mu hat represents the estimator of E[X]

Comment: Hello, @Xi'an I think I need to work on this part a little more. thank you for your time!